# How to deploy the integrated 3rd party directives in Angularjs project

Tags: angularjs, gulp

Say, I need to use Wysiwyg editor and I found a 3rd party directive for it.

It has a good readme and how to setup in my project(Local). 
Demo link: [Wysiwyg Editor](https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-wysiwyg)

Considering that I have done all the npms and integrations in my local project. 
How can I deploy the project with new changes?

Maybe I am asking because I don't know about gulp or bower. Does my project needs to have gulp ad bower in order to use such directives. If so, how will the deployment go post setup and integration.

**Assumption** : There are no gulpfile.js and bower setup already.

In Jquery using a plugin is quite simple. Add a script tag for js file of plugin and use it in html or js as instructed. Does the process has to complicated always for using a 3rd party angular directive?

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not compulsory to use gulp. Gulp just runs task like adding css,js to your file , minifing it and like.

you need to add js file which contain directive code. In your case it is

[this is your link of directive](https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-wysiwyg/blob/master/bower.json)

Now you can save this data in one of your js file and add it in index.html

OR

you can give this online link.

Using external directive need to add js n css file.

Question is will it work? We have to see dependancies of any external module we are using so what are dependancies of this module?

[enter link description here](https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-wysiwyg/blob/master/bower.json)

you need to add this module also

ADVANTAGES:

Using bower:  you can install module in your project. bower install will download all your dependancies also.

using gulp : Gulp task will make sure of adding your css and js files in index.html